# fuzzy rule extraction using fuzzy c-means

Tags: fuzzy, fuzzy-c-means-clustering

I have read an article which is about implementing classification methods using fuzzy-inference.

It has used c-means, in one of its parts, for extracting fuzzy-rules. 
It says we have a fuzzy-rule per cluster. (In fuzzification section)

Actually, I can not understand the relation between fuzzy-rule extraction and clusters using fuzzy c-means.

I would appreciate for any idea. the following link contains the article.
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5641997/